# CSS: can't see what is setting the max height of this element

Tags: css

At [this page](http://freightplus.com/beta/contact/), the fifth contact box extends into 2 columns, because America has 3 offices, and not two.

[image]

I'd like to increase the max height of the box so that all 3 offices fit in one column, but can't see any element that has a max height.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Those 2 boxes are 2 separate `.maininnerpage.grid12-3` elements, and they don't have a height or max-height. You can just add more text to it and it will make it taller. You'll likely need to increase the height of it's siblings so it doesn't look goofy.

Comment: you've got min-height: 530px on .white_bg

Comment: Give `.white_bg {
    min-height: height you want here;
}`

Comment: @MichaelCoker add an answer and I'll accept it if you like. Thank you.

Comment: @Steve just did, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those 2 boxes are 2 separate `.maininnerpage.grid12-3` elements, and they don't have a height or max-height. To increase the height of that box, you can just add more text to it and it will grow taller to fit the content. Although you'll likely need to increase the height of it's siblings so the UI is consistent and doesn't look goofy.

Answer (score 0):

In style.css line 1136

```
@media (min-width: 1024px)
.white_bg {
    min-height: 230px; // change this to what height you want
}
```